# Can Silverlight 4 establish a TCP connection to localhost?

Tags: c#, silverlight, sockets, silverlight-4.0

Please excuse the backwards architecture on this one and assume there's not a better way...

I have a Windows Service running on localhost, it listens on TCP port 5432 and broadcasts events to any connected sockets.

Is it possible for a Silverlight 4 in-browser app to connect to this service (thereby receiving these events)? Or are there security restrictions around Silverlight sockets preventing localhost access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - that is possible though not easy because of security reasons... please see the following links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28v=vs.95%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296248%28v=vs.95%29.aspx